# PHP warning from root directory

Tags: php

I have a problem with a php code.

**Folder name** what-counter This folder contains a file with the following php code named counter.php also the hitcount.txt file.

```
<?php

$filename = '../what-counter/hitcount.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
$hits = trim(fgets($handle)) + 1;
fclose($handle);

$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $hits);
fclose($handle);

// Uncomment the next line (remove //) to display the number of hits on your page.
echo $hits;

?>
```

The following php code is used in root directory files also in files from folders which echo's the hits.

```
<?php include("../what-counter/counter.php"); ?>
```

**The problem**
The code works in the files in folders but not in the files that are directly in the root directory.
Example: index.php is in the root directory

**Using this code i get this Warning**

```
<?php include("what-counter/counter.php"); ?>

Warning: fopen(../what-counter/hitcount.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/what/public_html/what-counter/counter.php on line 4

Warning: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/what/public_html/what-counter/counter.php on line 5

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/what/public_html/what-counter/counter.php on line 6

Warning: fopen(../what-counter/hitcount.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/what/public_html/what-counter/counter.php on line 8

Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/what/public_html/what-counter/counter.php on line 9

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/what/public_html/what-counter/counter.php on line 10
```

**And using this code i get this Warning**

```
<?php include("../what-counter/counter.php"); ?>

Warning: include(../what-counter/counter.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/what/public_html/include/footer.php on line 31

Warning: include(../what-counter/counter.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/what/public_html/include/footer.php on line 31

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../what-counter/counter.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/what/public_html
/include/footer.php on line 31
```

What can i do to the $filename url and `<?php include("../what-counter/counter.php"); ?>` to get it to work in files in root directory as well as folders?

Comment: if i remove ../ from the the file and the include it works on index.php pages but not in the folder files so it's something to do with the ../

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- Include relative the the file: `__DIR__.'/../somefile';`/`__DIR__.'/somepath/somefile';`
- Include relative to a known dir: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is often used, as is a `PROJECT_DIR`-like `define()` in your bootstrap code.
- Change the working directory to a known/static dir `chdir('/some/dir');`. Not recommended as calling code may not expect this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like absolute vs relative file problems...

Try replacing:

```
$filename = '../what-counter/hitcount.txt';
```

With, depending on where the file is located exactly, either of:

```
$filename = __DIR__ . '/what-counter/hitcount.txt';
$filename = dirname(__DIR__) . '/what-counter/hitcount.txt';
```

Or (if you're on an old php install) either of:

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/what-counter/hitcount.txt';
$filename = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/what-counter/hitcount.txt';
```